# Why do I get "connection refused" error when running my .NET GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: c#, github, .net-core, github-actions

I have create a `.yml` file on GitHub, but it fails every time when it runs.

I get this "connection refused" error:

[image]

The yml file is configured as below:

```yaml
name: .NET Core
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 5.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you running selenium tests or similar? It seems a ChromeDriver is in there, trying to connect to localhost on port 46001.

Comment: yes selenium c# and ii don't why it`s failed i tried to run the test on my machine and it run correctly, when i am trying to run on github action i got this error @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: Are you allowed to run selenium tests on the github platform?

Comment: How to know That, is not github Actions free open source? @LasseV.Karlsen